# Trying to create the database using ABP framework while DB Migration

Tags: multi-tenant, asp.net-core-3.1, abp

I have inserted  connectionstring  in "[AbpTenantConnectionStrings]" table for same tenant id.

My objective is to create both the DB and migrage the DB

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqQSZ.png)

while running below code only "Default Db is creating", can anyone let me know how to create and migrate other DB as well. what changes need to be done in the below code.

```
  var tenants = await _tenantRepository.GetListAsync(includeDetails: true);

            var migratedDatabaseSchemas = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach (var tenant in tenants)
            {
                using (_currentTenant.Change(tenant.Id))
                {
                    if (tenant.ConnectionStrings.Any())
                    {
                       

                        var tenantConnectionStrings = tenant.ConnectionStrings
                            .Select(x => x.Value)
                            .ToList();

                        if (!migratedDatabaseSchemas.IsSupersetOf(tenantConnectionStrings))
                        {
                            await MigrateDatabaseSchemaAsync(tenant);

                            migratedDatabaseSchemas.AddIfNotContains(tenantConnectionStrings);
                        }
                    }

                    await SeedDataAsync(tenant);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the below changes able to migrate or create the Db based on the connection-string inserted in "AbpTenantConnectionStrings":

```
 public async Task MigrateAsync()
    {
        var initialMigrationAdded = AddInitialMigrationIfNotExist();


        //var str = (await _connectionResolver.ResolveAsync("Default1"));

        if (initialMigrationAdded)
        {
            return;
        }

        Logger.LogInformation("Started database migrations...");

        await MigrateDatabaseSchemaAsync();
        await SeedDataAsync();

        Logger.LogInformation($"Successfully completed host database migrations.");

        var tenants = await _tenantRepository.GetListAsync(includeDetails: true);

        var migratedDatabaseSchemas = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var tenant in tenants)
        {
            using (_currentTenant.Change(tenant.Id))
            {
                if (tenant.ConnectionStrings.Any())
                {
                   

                    var tenantConnectionStrings = tenant.ConnectionStrings
                        .Select(x => x.Value)
                        .ToList();

                    tenantConnectionStrings.ForEach(async s =>
                    {                            
                            await MigrateDatabaseSchemaAsync(s);
                           // migratedDatabaseSchemas.AddIfNotContains(s);                          

                    });

                    //if (!migratedDatabaseSchemas.IsSupersetOf(tenantConnectionStrings))
                    //{
                    //    await MigrateDatabaseSchemaAsync(tenant);

                    //    migratedDatabaseSchemas.AddIfNotContains(tenantConnectionStrings);
                    //}
                }

                await SeedDataAsync(tenant);
            }

            Logger.LogInformation($"Successfully completed {tenant.Name} tenant database migrations.");
        }

        Logger.LogInformation("Successfully completed all database migrations.");
        Logger.LogInformation("You can safely end this process...");
    }



 private async Task MigrateDatabaseSchemaAsync(string str)
    {
        //Logger.LogInformation(
        //    $"Migrating schema for {(tenant == null ? "host" : tenant.Name + " tenant")} database...");

        foreach (var migrator in _dbSchemaMigrators)
        {
            await migrator.MigrateAsync(str);
        }
    }


 public interface IBookStoreDbSchemaMigrator
{
    Task MigrateAsync();
    Task MigrateAsync(string con);
}

 public class EntityFrameworkCoreBookStoreDbSchemaMigrator
    : IBookStoreDbSchemaMigrator, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public EntityFrameworkCoreBookStoreDbSchemaMigrator(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task MigrateAsync()
    {
        /* We intentionally resolving the BookStoreMigrationsDbContext
         * from IServiceProvider (instead of directly injecting it)
         * to properly get the connection string of the current tenant in the
         * current scope.
         */

        await _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<BookStoreMigrationsDbContext>()
            .Database
            .MigrateAsync();

    }

    public async Task MigrateAsync(string con)
    {

        var context = _serviceProvider
              .GetRequiredService<BookStoreMigrationsDbContext>();
        context.Database.SetConnectionString(con);
        context.Database.Migrate();

    }
}
```

Let me know if anyone has suggestions or a better approach.